# Distribution of balls into 'bins with given capacities' using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, dynamic-programming

I was wondering how to solve such a problem using DP.

Given n balls and m bins, each bin having max. capacity c1, c2,...cm. What is the total number of ways of distributing these n balls into these m bins.

The problem I face is

1. How to find a recurrence relation (I could when the capacities were all a single constant c).
2. There will be several test cases, each having its own set of c1,c2....cm. So how would the DP actually apply for all these test cases because the answer explicitly depends on present c1,c2....cm, and I can't store (or pre-compute) the answer for all combinations of c1,c2....cm.

Also, I could not come up with any direct combinatoric formula for this problem too, and I don't think one exists too.

Comment: Vote to move to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your function assuming the limits `c[0]`, `c[1]`, ... `c[m-1]` as fixed and then writing the recursive formula that returns the number of ways you can distribute n balls into bins **starting at index k**. With this approach a basic formula is simply

```
def solutions(n, k):
    if n == 0:
        return 1  # Out of balls, there's only one solution (0, 0, 0, 0 ... 0)
    if k == m:
        return 0  # Out of bins... no solutions
    total = 0
    for h in xrange(0, min(n, c[k])+1): # from 0 to c[k] (included) into bin k
        total += solutions(n - h, k + 1)
    return total
```

then you need to add memoization (this will be equivalent to a DP approach) and some other optimizations like e.g. that if `n > c[k] + c[k+1] + c[k+2] + ...` then you know there are no solutions without the need to search (and you can precompute the partial sums).

Comment: Well, seems like there can't be any relationship between two test sets, like {n,m and c1,c2,....cm} and {x,y and c1,c2,....cy}. But nonetheless there's enough scope for dynamic programming for a given test set too.

Answer (score 1):

1. There exists a combinatoric formula for this problem. The problem of finding the solutions to your problem is equivalent to finding the number of solutions of the equation

   `x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xm = n

   where xi < ci

   Which is equivalent to finding the cofficient of x^n in the following equation

   (1+x+..x^c1)(1+x+..+x^c2)...(1+x+...+x^cm)`
2. The recursion for this equation is pretty simple

   `M(i,j) = summation(M(i-1, j-k)) where 0<= k <= cj
   M(i,j) = 0   j <= 0
   M(i,1) = i given for every 1= 1
   M(i,j) is the number of ways of distributing the j balls in first i bins.`

For the Dynamic Programming part Solve this recursion by Memoization, You will get your DP Solution automatically.

Comment: Thanks snape for your comment. I had come across the formula you posted, but it's a little bit difficult to code and not very straightforward.
Secondly, I think the recursion should be -
M(i,j) = summation(M(i-k, j-1)) where 0<= k <= cj. 
But this recursion is not suitable for Dynamic Programming (or is it?). The sub-problems are not overlapping. And this would work for only one set of {n,m and c1,c2....cm} (or work for each of the sets independently) and I'm having several test cases. Would there be any relation between different test sets? Please correct if I'm wrong. My main aim is DP only.

Comment: Oh, well the sub-problems are overlapping for a given test set.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. This solution will work only for a certain test case. But some kind of optimization can be applied to solve the problem quite fast for multiple test cases too. I'll try to come up with such optimization.