# How to determine how many times will a statement inside a loop will be executed with conditional statements

Tags: c#, iteration, probability

There is a test that consists of 12 questions. each question must have a value greater than 4 points. all the question must add to 100. also all the questions must have an integer value. 
so a possible combination may be 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,45

there is a method that theoretically will give this result:

```
// this method will return the possible number of tests
public static double PosibleNumberOfTests()
{
    int q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12; // each question value

    double counter=0; // if there is a valid combination then counter will be increased by 1

    for (q12 = 5; q12 < 46; q12++)
    {
        for (q11 = 5; q11 < 46; q11++)
        {
            for (q10 = 5; q10 < 46; q10++)
            {
                for (q9 = 5; q9 < 46; q9++)
                {
                    for (q8 = 5; q8 < 46; q8++)
                    {
                        for (q7 = 5; q7 < 46; q7++)
                        {
                            for (q6 = 5; q6 < 46; q6++)
                            {
                                for (q5 = 5; q5 < 46; q5++)
                                {
                                    for (q4 = 5; q4 < 46; q4++)
                                    {
                                        for (q3 = 5; q3 < 46; q3++)
                                        {
                                            for (q2 = 5; q2 < 46; q2++)
                                            {
                                                for (q1 = 5; q1 < 46; q1++)
                                                {
                                                    if (q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + q7 + q8 + q9 + q10 + q11 + q12 == 100)
                                                        counter++;  // here is what we need. How many times will this line be executed!
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return counter;
}
```

note that I created each loop for values less than 46 because if all questions must have a value greater than 4 it will be impossible for a question to be worth 50 points for example.

### Edit

Sorry people I think I am not explaining my self clearly. I piked 12 questions as a random guess. This example may have been with a test with 100 questions. I need something like what dlev mentioned in his comment. I also know I can place breaks in the loops to make the method more efficient. if the sum is greater than 100 then why continue looping just brak out of the corresponding loop

Comment: please, for the love of god, don't run that code.

Comment: I know that lol. That's why I call it a theoretical method

Comment: So is your question: how do I figure out how many permutations exist that add up to 100?

Comment: I just want to know how many possible different test there could exist. remember each question has to be worth a minimum of 5 points. all the questions have to add to 100. possible combinations are:  5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,45  OR  5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,44  Or 5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10  etc...

Comment: This is a variation of integer partitioning. The standard problem is "For a given N, how many ways can I form a set of integers such that their sum is N?" Your problem just adds "The sets must be of size 12, and no element can be smaller than 5." See this wikipedia link, particularly the "Intermediate Function" section, for some ideas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29 (Note: if you care about the *order* of the questions as well, then you're talking about *compositions* rather than *partitions*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: @dlev, that should have been an answer. :)

Comment: what dlev said. this is the backpack problem right? plus permutation, just to make the answer really huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will evaluate the `if` statement `22,563,490,300,366,186,081` times. So needless to say, that ain't gonna work...

But with a few changes, it will. I'm not suggesting that brute force would be the way to go to solve this problem, but it does work.

First, to make the expressions a little simpler, observe that he have the same problem if every question must have a non-negative amount of points and the points have to add up to `40`.

Now, the first loop becomes `for (q12 = 0; q12 <= 40; q12++)`.

In the second loop, we don't have to test all `q11` between `0` and `40`, since `q11 + q12` can't be greater than `40`.

So, the second loop becomes `for (q11 = 0; q11 + q12 <= 40; q11++)`.

And so on...

Finally, the last `for` loop is completely unnecessary since there's only one possible value for `q1`.

So, change

```
for (q1 = 5; q1 < 46; q1++)
    if (q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + q7 + q8 + q9 + q10 + q11 + q12 == 100)
        counter++;
```

to

```
if (q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + q7 + q8 + q9 + q10 + q11 + q12 <= 40)
    counter++;
```

Not quick. Not elegant. But it works.

While this is much faster than the initial implementation, even if finding `1,000,000` "good" combinations per second, it will still take about 13 hours...

Let's change to problem to "each question must be worth at least 1 point and the sum of all points has to be 52". This is equivalent to the initial question.

We have `52` points to distribute. Each asterisk represents a point:

`****************************************************`

To do this, we may separate those points using delimiters. Eleven delimiters will give us `12` groups of asterisks.

Example: `****|*****|****|********|*|***|**|****|****|*********|***|*****`

Each delimiter must be between two adjacent asterisks. There are `51` of those spaces.

Since the delimiters present no differences, the solution is also the solution of the question "in how many different, order-independent ways can `11` items be allocated in `51` spots.

The number of `11`-combinations from a given set of `51` elements is `51! / ( 40! * 11! )` which gives us `47,626,016,970`.

This all is assuming that "order matters", i. e., it's different if question 1 is worth 10 points and question 2 is worth 20 points or viceversa.

For `q` questions, each worth more than `p` points and a total of `t` points on the test, the formula would be:

`(t - p * q - 1)! / ( (t - (p + 1) * q)! * (q - 1)! )`

Comment: Dennis I don't think you understood the question lol. or maybe I am missing something...

Comment: oh I see what you mean. that is a good point! yeah I also have to add breaks so that if the loop is over 100 it will be faster to break from the method.

Comment: I want to be able to tell the output of the method without having to run it. if this where a test with 100 questions using your technique will definitely make it much more simpler but it will take months to execute. I need a formula for that kind of problem... Sorry for not explaining my self clearly

Comment: Yeah, but my math was a little off. But ain't gonna work either. See edit.

Comment: yeah but I understood what you meant. I did not thought about that. I thought of stepping out of the loop if the sum was greater than 100 for example but your technique is much more pimplier to implement and will def have to be there if I where planing on executing that method

Comment: +1 Very neat solution, although it took me an hour to figure it out myself! Thanks for refreshing my memory. High school math has been so damn hard these days!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you encounter a counting question, it's always a good idea to subtract constants first. In this case, the minimum value for each question is 5, so subtract that from each value and from the total. This gives you a maximum total of 40 with a minimum of 0 for each question. Then at the end, when you present the actual solution, you can add the constants again.

Now look at this question: [Distribution of balls into 'bins with given capacities' using Dynamic Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662561).

Your problem is the same, except that it's a little bit simpler. It's the same because your questions correspond to the bins and the values correspond to the balls.

Yours is simpler because in your case, the capacity of the questions is not limiting. In the accepted answer to the above question, `min(n, c[k])` is always equal to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

### The answer from my teacher: (same as what you guys gave thanks!)

[image]

[image]